# Determining the object detected in sensor

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

Is there a way to determine which object has been detected with the sensor?
For example, if the owner's collisions sensor turns positive, is it possible to get the object collided with?

Something like this:

```
if own.collisionSensor.positive:
   obj1 = owner of detected collision object
   (print obj1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, found the answer:

it would be:

`if collision.positive:
        obj1 = collision.hitObjectList[0]`